# Can I get Char iterator that have bigger sliding window? java/scala

Tags: java, scala

Im working with a file which is scala `BufferedSource`, and it had `iter` object which is `Pattern: iter: Iterator[Char]`.

Im passing this char iterator to a function that iterates on the char's and adding some of the chars to StringBuilder.

To be able to use this function when iterating on the chars im using helper funcs that needs the previous, current and next chars...

how can i manage something like this?

Comment: `file.iter.toSeq.sliding(3,1).toSeq` might help to achieve your requirement..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code, sometimes even pseudo-code, is usually more instructive and helpful than vague descriptions of code as you've offered.

You might be able to use `sliding` to get at previous/current/next.

```
val ci = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toIterator  // Iterator[Char]

val sci = ci.sliding(3)  // GroupedIterator[Char]
sci.next  // List[Char] = List(a, b, c)
sci.next  // List[Char] = List(b, c, d)
```

But this often creates its own headaches because the receiving code doesn't know if it's looking at the first iteration (the "previous" char hasn't been processed) or the final (the "next" char won't be seen again).

It might be more advantageous to simply buffer the iterator so that you can peek at the coming element before consuming it.

```
val ci = "ab".toIterator  // Iterator[Char] = non-empty iterator

val bci = ci.buffered  // scala.collection.BufferedIterator[Char]
bci.next     // Char = a
bci.hasNext  // Boolean = true
bci.head     // Char = b
bci.next     // Char = b
bci.hasNext  // Boolean = false
```